# Putting some upcoming positions in CV

Tags: mathematics, funding, postdocs, cv

I am going to apply for a Postdoc position which starts six month later. I am a postdoc in institute A and have new grant in institute B to start in upcoming month. Can I put this position and grant in my CV? Since I have not started that yet.

Comment: Is this for a position at institute C, or is this a fellowship or similar that is meant to fund you, for example to continue work at B?

Comment: It is in C , I mean in another country

Comment: Does "I have a new grant" mean that you applied for and got a grant, or that somebody else did?

Comment: I got that, but the time which I can start my work in the next month

Comment: Still unclear. Did you write and submit the application in your name?

Answer (score 2):

If the contract for the grant is finalized, you can list it as an achievement on your CV.

Comment: When I applied funding, I am often asked about past, current, and pending support. I don't see why they shouldn't list it as "pending" if they have a decision letter.